# Wordpress import worked but can't access posts or pages

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I've recently setup on my new VPS and successfully installed and imported my sql databse. However, after trying to click on any posts/pages, i get an error that the page can't be found.

> Not Found

Logged in as admin, I can see all the posts and pages, yet clicking view just gives me the same message. The fact they are here means it must of imported them, just can't work out why I can't access them :S

Help!

Comment: Have you checked that your permalink structure matches what the original installation was using?

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit the posts in the admin, then you probably have the data and this is a url rewriting issue.

Try re-saving your permalinks, even without making a change.

If you can see the list of posts, but can't edit them then you probably have a bad import.